# buffalo dd-wrt access point/range extender without wires?

Tags: dd-wrt

I'm not sure exactly what access points are. I assumed them to be basically a wifi range extender, but now i'm guessing not. My situation is quite simple. I have purchased a buffalo router (WHR-HP-G300N). I already have a wireless router (2WIRE from AT&T) that provides the home internet. Unfortunately, it had to be placed on one end of the house. I wish to place my buffalo router in the middle of my house to get a better quality connection (currently it's quite poor on the other end). How can I make my buffalo router re-distribute the wireless pushed out by the 2WIRE? From what I can make out, making it an access point requires having a wire connecting both routers. This is not an option, so how can I do all this wirelessly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Buffalo re-names "repeater" for their own "WDS" system.

Answer (score 0):

An **access point** takes a wired connection and distributes it wirelessly. A **repeater** (or **range extender**) receives a wireless connection and re-distributes it - no wires involved.

Your router can be either of these if your router has DD-WRT firmware installed. According to [this DD-WRT wiki entry](http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WHR-HP-G300N), your router should have DD-WRT on it, depending on when it was manufactured. Visit your router's webpage (most likely at 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.2.1) to see if it has DD-WRT installed (you'll see "DD-WRT" at the top of the page) If it does, [here's a video guide on how to setup a DD-WRT repeater](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOlpDwh7f1s).

Comment: The problem is though, there is no "repeater" option. The options are AP, client, client bridge, and their own special AP and Station modes.

Comment: Try updating your firmware and see if the option is there, perhaps.

Comment: did that too. no change.